# C# Using browse textbox for folderpath

Tags: c#

The program i am working on patches/updates the clients game...

The game it is made for is very old and it has 2 patches. For a person to play they need to install the patch. Once the patch is installed if they decide they want to play using the other patch they have to uninstall everything and start again.

The program i have made has two buttons. Version1 and Version2. When they click Version1 button it searches C:\PROGRA~1\Game\ For files, deletes specified files and then copy's files from the folder that comes with my program installed in program files. to the game path.

I realized i am using the above path. But if they aren't using windows 32 bit this will not work. How do i determine the clients program files location if i am using inno setup?

EDIT: Soory guys edited question my head wasn't straight when i asked my previous question.

Comment: I"m having a tough time understanding what you're asking.. maybe you could rephrase you question a bit?

Comment: Why aren't you saving the install location during the install (in a registry entry, for instance) so you can find it again easily later?

Comment: It sounds like you need to review some things.. because generally all you need to do is use relative paths.. for example, Application.StartupPath will give you the lcoation where your .exe is.. if you use that you should never have to ask the user for such a thing. example:

string myINFpath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "InfFiles");

And if you create an msi installer you can add those files to your install lcoation as well.. you don't need to care where the user installs your game.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you're after is string.IsNullOrEmpty(). You test to see if the textbox text is null or empty, like so:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
```

..then you build your path based on that. For example:

```
string BuildFilePath()
{
    return string.Concat(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text) ? textBox.Text : @"C:\Program Files\Game\Folder\etc", @"\Cool.inf");
}

string filePath = BuildFilePath();

if (file.Exists(filePath))
    // etc..
```

I hope that makes sense.

EDIT: Moved the complicated concatenation into its own method, because I'm a bit of a "Clean Code" preacher.

Comment: Never hard code install locations.. you don't know where your exe will end up on the client machine.

Comment: The exe in his question isn't referenced in the path. He is looking for the path for a game that is installed on the client machine. I don't see a more elegant way of finding that folder other than, <default_vendor_path> first and if that fails, prompt the user to find the path for you (which could be anywhere). That is what the OP is asking.

Comment: I see. Quite difficult to understand exactly what he meant by the post. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Why aren't you saving the install location during the install (in a registry entry, for instance) so you can find it again easily later? – Ken White 2 hours ago <-- Ken, how would i do this if i am using Inno Setup?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
if (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(textBox1.Text,"Cool.inf")))
   File.Delete(System.IO.Path.Combine(textBox1.Text,"Cool.inf"));
```